# Lyapunov Exponent Python Implementation

Tags: python, statistics

I have 10k data points like this:

```
0.010222
0.010345
0.010465
0.010611
0.010768
0.010890
0.011049
0.011206
0.011329
0.011465
0.011613
0.11763
0.011888
0.012015
0.012154
0.012282
0.012408
0.012524
....
```

I want to calculate Lyapunov exponent for that. This is what I've done so far:

```
lyapunovs = []
eps = 0.0001
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        if np.abs(data[i] - data[j]) < eps:
            for k in range(1, min(N - i, N - j)):
                 d0 = np.abs(data[i] - data[j])
                 dn = np.abs(data[i + k] - data[j + k])
                 lyapunovs.append(math.log(dn) - math.log(d0))  # problem
```

My problem is that I don't know first Lyapunov exponent is average of all the  `lyapunovs` when `k = 1` or average of all the `lyapunovs` for the first time that `data[i] - data[j] < eps`?

**Is this right implementation for Lyapunov exponent?**

And this is the [Numerical Calculation of Lyapunov Exponent](https://www.bu.edu/abl/files/physicad_rosenstein93.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I see from the chosen loop structure in the question that a triangle of the Cartesian product of the points is being used. This might improve the estimate of the derivatives, which are susceptible to noise, but it is not part of the [Lyapunov exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) explicitly. See [this example](http://systems-sciences.uni-graz.at/etextbook/sw2/lyapunov.html) of the calculations on a known function in the absence of measurement error. Feel free to look into that aspect more, but below I will assume the comparison of signal points adjacent in time.

Your original question uses NumPy, so I will also make use of it. One of the rules of thumb to using NumPy well is to avoid loops, although it is possible to [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) functions that contain loops. With no explicit time measurements, and no repeated values, you could simply do:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(0,1,size=10**4) # Mock signal data
np.mean(np.log(np.abs(np.diff(x))))
```

Or if the signal is paired with an array of timepoints, then the numerical derivative can involve time:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(0,1,size=10**4) # Mock signal data
t = np.arange(10**4) # Mock time data
np.mean(np.log(np.abs(np.diff(x) / np.diff(t))))
```

However, in some datasets it is possible for adjacent values to repeat! This can occur when you've measured the signal only to a few decimal places, and it is a problem because it leads to `np.log(0)` (=`-np.inf`) which will blow up your calculation. A simple solution is to remove duplicated values, but this will only be suitable if duplicates are relatively rare and you have a large sample size. It is possible to estimate an upper bound on the estimate of the L-exponent by considering the precision of your measurements, but that is not the estimate of the L-exponent itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the Lyapunov Exponent in this way and then output the results as tuples in a file see blog:

https://blog.abhranil.net/2014/07/22/calculating-the-lyapunov-exponent-of-a-time-series-with-python-code/:

```
from math import log
import numpy as np

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [float(i) for i in f.read().split()]

N = len(data)
eps = 0.001
lyapunovs = [[] for i in range(N)]

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i + 1, N):
        if np.abs(data[i] - data[j]) < eps:
            for k in range(min(N - i, N - j)):
                lyapunovs[k].append(log(np.abs(data[i+k] - data[j+k])))

with open('lyapunov.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(lyapunovs)):
        if len(lyapunovs[i]):
            string = str((i, sum(lyapunovs[i]) / len(lyapunovs[i])))
            f.write(string + '\n')
```

Comment: This looks like the following blog: https://blog.abhranil.net/2014/07/22/calculating-the-lyapunov-exponent-of-a-time-series-with-python-code/

Comment: this is neither the asnwer nor the way

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that knowing the literal expression is the best.

I will take an example with the logistic map equation :

```
def logisticmap(x_init, r, length):
    x = [x_init]
    for t in range(length):
       x.append(r*x[-1]*(1-x[-1]))
    return np.array(x)
```

Now let's generate the data :

```
x = logistic(0.2, 3.92, 1000)
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

[Plot logistic map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87aUR.png)

Here is the proposed solution by Galan,

```
np.mean(np.log(abs(np.diff(x))))
```

Which gives : *-1.0379*

When you derive the Lyapunov exponent from the logistic map equation :

```
np.mean(np.log(abs(r*(1-2*x))))
```

It gives : *0.538296*

Which is the actual true value for the Lyapunov, since the system is in its chaotic regime it must be positive, so I guess the evaluation from data points is not working in this example, you can try with more data points, but it will still give you a negative LE.

Unfortunately I don't know enough to guide you towards a better estimation for the Lyapunov if you can't derive a mathematical expression, but I would be intersted to know !

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reduce computational complexity with numpy vectorization.

```
def lyapunov_exponent(series: np.array, threshold: float): -> np.array
    
    N = len(series)
    eps = threshold
    
    L = [np.array([0]*N)]
    for i in range(1, N):
        diff = np.abs(series[i:]-series[:-i])
        dist = np.log(diff)
        L.append(np.concatenate([[0]*i, dist]))
    L = np.array(L)
    
    tf_L = np.where(L<eps, 1, 0)
    count_L = np.zeros_like(tf_L)
    
    for i in range(N):
        indices = ( np.array(range(0,N-i)), np.array(range(i,N)) )
        count_L[indices] = np.cumsum(tf_L[indices])
    
    avg = np.sum(count_L * L, axis=0) / np.sum(count_L, axis=0)
    
    return avg
```

If there is room for improvement or you get some different result than already answered, please reply.